# spamassassin tries to use /nonexistent even though its user has a valid home directory

Tags: freebsd, exim, spamassassin

I have a spamassassin daemon used by exim on a FreeBSD 9.3 System that tries to use /nonexistent for its temp files and bayes-filter storage.

Passing the username or a home directory via the daemons flags in /etc/rc.conf does nothing to change this behaviour.

```
spamd_flags="-c -u spamd -H /var/spool/spamd"
```

The child processes spawned by the initial process are run by the user spamd (whose home directory is `/var/spool/spamd`), but it still tries to use /nonexistent. The permissions of the directory are correct:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 spamd     spamd    3 Dec 20 18:15 spamd
```

Setting a `bayes_path` in `/usr/local/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf` does not change this behaviour either.

Apparently I'm not the only one [who had the problem](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2007-February/142924.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem has nothing to do with spamassassin itself, it is the way it is used by exim. In my exims configuration I had this line in its ACL section:

```
warn    spam       = nobody
```

when I replaced that with

```
warn    spam       = spamd
```

everything worked as intended